# What adapter do I need to mount a Sigma Ashperical 24-70mm zoom lens on a Canon DSLR?

Tags: canon, lens-mount, lens-adapter, sigma

[image: Sigma lense details]
[image: Signma lense front]
[image: Sigma lense back]
[image: mount]

I have an EOS 4000D body and I already own a PK-EF lens adapter which I use for my Tokina lenses. I recently acquired this Sigma Aspherical Zoom lense and it doesn't mount using my current adapter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Sigma and other lens makers that are not camera makers build lenses with different mounts.  The important thing is not what lens it is, but what mount it is made for.

Answer (score 4):

That lens is for Minolta “A” mount for Minolta film cameras with autofocus.

It is not possible for a Canon camera to control the autofocus or aperture of a Minolta “A” mount Sigma lens.

You can buy an adapter that will mount an older Minolta MC/MD lens to a Canon EF or EF-S mount DSLR camera, or a Minolta “A” lens to a Canon Mirrorless camera, but it will not be fully functional. These adapters are really designed for manual focus, manual aperture lenses only.

There is also at least one Minolta “A” mount to Canon EF mount adapter available but it requires an additional optical element in order to correct for infinity focus. This extra optical element acts a a focal length multiplier and reduces image quality.

Do not buy this lens, or if you already own it, sell it and buy a Canon compatible lens instead.

Comment: Thanks for your input I really appreciate it!
I happened to have gotten a Minolta A film camera and tried it out this afternoon and works brilliantly with it. Thanks again!